# Histogram for big data set

Tags: mapreduce, analytics, histogram

I want to draw histogram for 1GB data using map reduce. Not able to get any hold after googling. Please give suggestions for any specific library in python or java.

Comment: it seems you are asking how to do word count in mapreduce ?

Comment: Are you using Hadoop? If so, check out the ValueHistogram class: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aggregate/ValueHistogram.html

Comment: Yes, I am using hadoop. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

ValueHistogram in hadoop can be used for drawing histogram.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aggregate/ValueHistogram.html